# Batch Update jsonb field based on mapping

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql table that looks like this

```
 aid (bigint) |  information (jsonb)                              
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 123456789123 | {"settings": ["abc", "def"]}
...
```

I have a mapping of about 1000 strings like `{"abc": "xyz", "def": "klm"}`.
I need to update the settings based on the mapping so the above example would become
`{"settings": ["xyz", "klm"]}`

I have about 30 million rows that I need to update.

1. Is there a way for me to do the updating in a single query, so I don't have to query the settings, process the settings, and then query to update?
2. How would I structure this query to do batching? I need to update about 30 million records so I don't want to be updating one record at a time.

Thank you!

P.S. I'm not using an ORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it over the whole set of 30M records in one go. Here is my suggestion.
Iterate over `information -> settings` jsonb array of each row (`jsonb_array_elements_text`) then aggregate the mapped value into a jsonb array (`jsonb_agg`) and then replace the value of `settings` (`jsonb_set`).

```sql
-- test case
create temporary table the_table (aid  integer, information jsonb);
insert into the_table values (123, '{"settings": ["abc", "def"]}');
insert into the_table values (124, '{"settings": ["abc", "def"]}');
insert into the_table values (125, '{"settings": ["abc", "def"]}');
select * from the_table;

-- update statement
update the_table set information = jsonb_set
(
 information, 
 '{settings}', 
 (
   select jsonb_agg(coalesce('{"abc": "xyz", "def": "klm"}'::jsonb ->> v, v))
   from jsonb_array_elements_text(information -> 'settings') v
 )
);

select * from the_table;
```

Result:

| aid | information |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {"settings": ["xyz", "klm"]} |
| 124 | {"settings": ["xyz", "klm"]} |
| 125 | {"settings": ["xyz", "klm"]} |

Comment: thanks!
it looks like currently if there are unmapped values then a bunch of values including the mapped ones turn into null
```-- test case
insert into the_table values (123, '{"settings": ["abc", "def"]}');
insert into the_table values (124, '{"settings": ["hij", "x-y-z"]}');
insert into the_table values (125, '{"settings": ["q-w-e"]}');

mapping
{"abc": "x-y-z", "h-i-j": "k-l-m"}
```
If there's not another way I can have a mapping that also maps values to themselves - though I'd rather not risk accidentally nullifying all my data

Comment: it also doesn't have to be one query for all the data - chunks is fine. i'd just rather not have to retrieve the data, use code to generate the new values, then set back the data

Comment: Well, that's pretty straightforward. Simply update `'{"abc": "xyz", "def": "klm"}'::jsonb ->> v` to `coalesce('{"abc": "xyz", "def": "klm"}'::jsonb ->> v, v)`. You do not need chunks, 30M is not much database-wise. Answer updated.

Comment: Retrieve the data, use code to generate the new values, then set back the data is a bad idea if you can do the same in place on the db server. It would be orders of magnitude slower and may have concurrency issues.

Comment: Thank you!
With this kind of query is there any kind of risk of incoming requests to the database getting backed up though?

Comment: I do not understand 'backed up' in your question. Pls. have a look at [Postgresql MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html) for explanation.